# How to concat all values of single column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have column A in the Sample Table1.
Column A has values as follows.

```
+----+
| A  |
+----+
| a1 |
| a2 |
| a3 |
| a4 |
| a5 |
+----+
```

I need a query that should give the following output.
All the Values should be

```
"a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a combination of *[`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)* and *[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)*

**Query**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', A, '"')) AS `combined_A`
FROM `your_table_name`;
```

And if you want to remove the duplicates. Then use `DISTINCT` with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

**Query**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('"', `A`, '"')) AS `combined_A`
FROM `your_table_name`;
```

***[`SQL Fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09a3a/3)***

Comment: What if I need `a1&a2&a3&a4&a5` (no `,` in between)?

Comment: @June : You can use `separator '&'` with `Group_Concat`

Answer (score 3):

**Use GROUP_CONCAT() function to achive this.**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(<Type your column name here> SEPARATOR ', ') FROM <Table Name>;
```

**Query for your provided sample example :**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A SEPARATOR ', ')  FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a [group conca](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)t function to accomplish something similar

SELECT , GROUP_CONCAT(A SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM Table1 GROUP BY

In the event you don't have an id you will have to use a constant for the grouping. Also note that the result you have  has a 1024 byte character limit [unless you override it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)

Comment: No GROUP BY in this instance